# How to get a non-fixed table cell to show ellipsis

Tags: css, html

I have an interesting CSS question for some of you CSS wizards. I have a table that has user generated content, and I want to limit long columns to a maximum width. The table is not fixed layout, and the column widths are user-specified too but by default should have a maximum width.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Header 1</td><td>Header 2</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Long Text Here</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I added `overflow: hidden`, `white-space: nowrap`, and `text-overflow: ellipsis` to the header's css class, and in the above html the text 'Long Text Here' pushes the width of that column out. But this makes it so that the column width can only be that text length or longer.

What can I do - other than use fixed layout - to make a cell shrink, and show ellipses?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a bunch of different strategies for how to size the column here (e.g. make it the width of the shortest text, the width of the average text, big enough to fit 80% of the entries…). Do you have one in mind in particular? The easiest is probably to give the column a fixed maximum width with `max-width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option would be to set a maximum width on the column, so that a few really long entries don't make it ludicrously wide. For example, to do this for the first column:

```css
td:first-child {
  max-width: 5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Header 1</td><td>Header 2</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Really, Ridiculously Long Text Here</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

(You could use `:nth-child()`, or maybe classes, to restrict other columns.)

This solution requires the maximum width to be set in the CSS, however, which might not be very useful for dynamic content. Instead, you could set it in `style` attributes in the HTML directly, which is easier to do using JavaScript or your templating system:

```css
td:first-child, th:first-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th style="max-width: 5em">Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td style="max-width: 5em">Text</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="max-width: 5em">Text</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="max-width: 5em">Really, Ridiculously Long Text Here</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Here is a codepen showing more in-depth what I want to see. Notice TH elements cannot support this trick. Nor can I get a dynamic max-width in a style tag.... I'd have to set my table up *exactly* like yours to get it to do that.

https://codepen.io/radnen/pen/xzEbeb

Comment: Ah, I see. (You should edit your question to specify that you want to set the maximum width of the column.) The reason that figure B doesn't work there is that you're only applying the maximum width to the first `<th>` element, so it will only apply to the header. If you add `style="max-width: 80px;"` to each of the `<td>` elements for the first column, it works.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered. It seems that must be the solution. Every cell or at least a top most TD cell of the tbody needs the width css parameter set. Thanks!

Comment: Just want to add a final comment. I went to my code; implemented this in the real environment (outside of toy demos) and I'm going to verify 100% that this is working. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure if you are asking for something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/o6x1nt93/15/

```css
table{
  width:100%;
}
td {
  width:50%;
  float:left; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close and similar to Harry Cutts answer below. See my comment linking to the codepen that has more of what I'm trying to achieve. I don't think it's possible in CSS?

Comment: I am not sure if I am undertanding you, so you want to control the size of td ... if you put float:left; attribute you can control it and play width the size you desire